Creating ReportFooter Total in Devexpress Report
I have this report (which is working perfectly), but I want to print a SUM(Grand Total) of each productName(i.e: CARGO 0.58, CARGO 0.53, etc) in the ReportFooter.
I had used: BeforePrint event to add total according to the ProductoNombre, but i have: object no set error.  I had used _AfterPrint to do the same and nothing
Any idea please?
Thanks
Header and details and the ReportFooter
I used these code in _BeforePrint and _AfterPrint event to get the Field PrecioTotal and the sum according to the Label Text of ProductoNombre
double total = Convert.ToDouble(GetCurrentColumnValue("PrecioTotal"));

switch (xrLabel46.Text)
{
    case "CARGO 0.58":
       xrLabel61.Text = (total + Convert.ToDouble(xrLabel61.Text)).ToString();
       break;
    case "CARGO 0.53":
        break;
    default:
        break;
}


I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, but it seems you need to create another report for calculating grand-totals for each productName and then add this report at the end of report-footer of current report.

If you want to calc the grand total for each item separately using print events, a separate variable for each one should be declared and initialized (outside the events) and requires the number of items to be fixed and limited to a reasonable amount.
